# Patio Roofing Question - Transparent corrugated pvc covering

Tags: outdoor, patio, roofing

I have recently built a free-standing patio covering that backs up to the back of our house.  It is approx 24 x 14.  I'm having trouble deciding what to put as a covering.

First I thought the Ondura roofing (http://ondura.com/?gclid=CNSyxcGctc0CFUZrfgodkKMO7w) but bad reviews have scared me away.

Then I thought some translucent corrugated roofing.  But not sure whether it will provide sufficient shade.  The point of this patio is to get us out of the summer heat!  Does anyone have experience with this type of roofing?  I know it comes in different "shades" but will it provide good shade, or am I better off going with a solid metal/pvc roofing?

Also, will the corrugated pvc type covering last?  I don't want to be replacing the roof after a few years.

Comment: I have a deck that is covered with poly? Clear corrugated it keeps the rain off but still lets some light into the back of the house. The first year I thought it was two clear but now several years later it is awesome, very easy to clean the tree leaves and dust off that fiberglass hangs on to, We like the light but the shade it provides is nice on hot days, it is not as clear as it first was but think it will last at least a few more years , metal roofing will last much longer but will be hotter in my experience and block all the light , probably about the same as the clear poly to clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be (or had better be) polycarbonate or acrylic, not PVC, or it will die in the sun.

If you find it too clear to begin with, greenhouse suppliers have "paint on shade" and/or shadecloth, both come in white and in colors.

If all you want is shade, shadecloth might be a better choice than roofing, but of course it does not block rain. Shadecloth suspended above the glazing would likely do a slight better job of blocking heat than either paint or shadecloth laid right on the roofing.

Metal will be simply broiling hot.

Comment: thanks - I went with metal for the durability and nice look.  So far, so good